# Ubuntu installs, Kubuntu won't?

Tags: kubuntu

I gave my brother a usb drive with Kubuntu 18.04 on it to try on his brand new desktop that came without an operating system. He tried to run the live system before installing but got the error:

AMD-Vi:Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter
Couldn't get size: xxxxxxxxxxx
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list

I assume this relates to secure boot, in the BIOS I can see CSM which I think is the thing I'm looking for?
However, after trying various combinations of the CSM options he still can't get it to boot. 
Strangely when he tries Ubuntu 18.04 it boots from USB without problem.
The motherboard is a Gigabyte AM4.

[image]

Any suggestions for getting Kubuntu to work please?

Comment: Did you verify the install-media (at the first menu before try/install) you can check install media to confirm the download & write was perfect.  This check takes maybe a minute, but saves hours of diagnostics later & is well worth it. I can't recall the Kubuntu installer boot processor, but if you see a keyboard/person-in-circle hit space (or a key) and you'll get menu with the option (if it wasn't already shown.

Comment: @guiverc is right: The base system and kernel for all flavors of 18.04 are identical - only the desktop environment is different. Since one boots, they should all boot...unless you have a corrupt ISO or a bad burn.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have the Kubuntu USB here and it boots fine on my desktop. I have now downloaded Ubuntu Mate and will try that on his new pc. I'm right to think I should be able to install any Ubuntu based distro without changes to CSM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e)