# MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e

Tags: mac

Problem on a Mac Mini Mid 2011. I have looked through other articles and couldn't get help. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu @Ashton Gamer Since this is your first time posting here, to improve your chances of getting an answer, please describe in detail your problem, by including just enough information (such as the text output of your terminal) to allow others to reproduce/resolve the problem. Also, tell us what steps did you take and what solution you've tried so far.

Comment: You can check the answer provided here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380700&s=34fc6a2476083fbd849d8d72521e6190&p=13732697#post13732697

Answer (score 15):

Add the grub arguments `noapic noacpi nosplash` in place of `quiet splash`. `noapic` and `noacpi` are kernel boot options. ACPI stands for Advanced Configuration and Power Interface and APIC stands for Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller.

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this:

[image: GNU GRUB menu screen]

Press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter editing mode. This will bring up a GNU GRUB screen that looks like this:

[image: GNU GRUB screen]

Use the arrow keys to navigate when screen editing the above screen. Navigate to after the string on this screen that starts with `root=`. In this example screen the full string is `root=` followed by `UUID=` and a hexadecimal string as shown below:

```
root=UUID=bcf15ef2-a0b2-4753-9558-8399dd12a729
```

Immediately after this string replace `quiet splash` by `noapic noacpi nosplash`. This change is only temporary — it will just be used once and GRUB won't remember it in the future. It may be possible to make these changes permanent by changing the ACPI and APIC settings in the Mac Mini's UEFI firmware. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with the kernel boot options that were added. If you make a mistake, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to the previous screen.

Comment: İt works for my Lenovo flex 5 , in addition i pulled out the USB  and inserted it again while the Ubuntu  screen start .

Comment: @karel What happens if there is no line that says "root"? (I am not using a Mac Mini, is it specific to that hardware?)

Comment: @ComputerScientist The GNU GRUB screen is not specific to Mac Mini hardware. For another example of a similar GNU GRUB screen on Debian see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457189/). For an example of a different type of boot screen on openSUSE Leap see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471282/).

Comment: What does this do?  For me it still goes into recovery mode, the error is still there in `journalctl -xb`.

Comment: @YanKingYin Please ask it as separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Use a live usb of the same ubuntu version.
Open terminal.

```
sudo -i
fsck /dev/sdaX
```

Replace 'X' with your root disk name,and then with all other drives present.
You can check it with "fdisk -l".
Reboot.Remove live usb.
Ta-da, its done.

Comment: You don't need live CD :) just press Enter and you will have root, then do fdisk and fsck :)

Comment: @madzohan:  but how can I unmount `/` to run `fsck` on that partition?