# cannot boot 5.x: Couldn't get UEFI db list

Tags: boot, kernel

I have currently Ubuntu 18.04 with Kernel 4.20

I tried to upgrade to Kernel 5.14 and 5.16 but it hangs on boot. It shows the message

> Couldn't get UEFI db list

which is then followed by a black screen.

I installed the kernel with ukuu. There was something mentioned with **EFI**. May this be the cause?

[image]

Here the last log bot that I got through `journalctl -b -1 -e`

```
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Closed Syslog Socket.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped ACPI Events Check.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Closed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped target System Initialization.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopping Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Time Synchronization...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Apply Kernel Variables.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save Random Seed...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /swapfile...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save Random Seed.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot/efi...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/win/Lager...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/win/BigLager...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 ntfs-3g[1060]: Unmounting /dev/sdc1 (Lager)
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 ntfs-3g[1077]: Unmounting /dev/sdb2 (Lager)
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/win/Lager.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/win/BigLager.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/DE4E-B26A.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Starting Reboot...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 kernel: printk: systemd-shutdow: 44 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Jul 16 23:17:44 adam-MS-7A63 systemd-journald[439]: Journal stopped
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have UEFI Secure Boot on? Or setting like this user? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380700

Comment: @oldfred I have secure boot disabled because I have dual boot with windows and I would have to disable/enable it each time I switch platform. Maybe its easiest if I just reinstall ubuntu on my harddrive.

Comment: UEFI has Windows Secure Boot key. Ubuntu uses Windows key if you have Secure boot on. The only place you need to add a key is if Secure Boot is on and you want to add a proprietary driver. Ubuntu cannot certify proprietary drivers even if common driver. But now walk a user thru adding his own key to allow adding proprietary driver. Easier just to have Secure Boot off. Microsoft required all vendors to let users turn off UEFI Secure Boot, so you have a setting somewhere, just ever vendor does it somewhat different.

Comment: @oldfred Im a bit confused what I have to change now. I have found two settings in bios related to that: 1. `secure boot mode` which is on `standard` and could be changed to `custom`. 2. `secure boot support` which is disabled and when I try to enable it I get a error message: "need platform key" - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158895/how-to-create-platform-key-for-secure-boot

Comment: First comment above has user with custom & standard settings, said to use standard. But I have only seen systems with UEFI Secure boot on or off and usually not called Secure Boot but "Windows" or "Other" and use "Other" for Windows 7 since Windows 7 does not support Secure Boot (or Other is really Secure Boot off).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e)

Answer (score 1):

I began getting similar errors only after upgrading the kernel.

The errors seem to be related to an attempt to import UEFI keys for Secure Boot.
I do not have Secure Boot enabled in my BIOS but do only boot in UEFI.
I was able to stop the errors simply by changing a setting in the BIOS from `[Customized]` to `[Standard]` for Secure Boot Mode.

The Customized setting allows you to modify the secure boot keys manually. The Standard just sets the default keys.

Note: This fixed my error even though I previously had Secure Boot [Disabled] in BIOS settings.

Security -> Secure Boot -> Secure Boot Mode -> [Standard]

Hope this can possibly help you and others.

Comment: @Adam Please try to understand this answer. It doesn't imply enabling Secure Boot, actually the opposite. The problem is triggered by a Secure Boot **setting**. Just change it to standard.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yeah sorry my comment was wrong. I have `secure boot mode` on standard already, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158895/how-to-create-platform-key-for-secure-boot

Comment: @Adam, if the 'secure boot mode' setting was already set to 'Standard', then set it to '**Disabled**', and try, it should work.

Comment: @SimonGomes I can toogle  'secure boot mode' between `standard` and `custom` but in the description it says that this is only relevant if `secure boot support` is enabled. However, `secure boot support` is disabled and I cannot enable it because I have a PK. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158895/how-to-create-platform-key-for-secure-boot

Comment: @Adam, then do this, set the `secure boot mode` from `standard` to **`custom`**. Then somewhere in your bios you should have an option for `Key Management`, select that, and select `Platform Key (PK)` and then pick `Set new`. Then come back and change the `secure boot mode` from `custom` to **`standard`** and then try to `Enable` the `secure boot mode`. See if this works, if not there should also be another option in your bios that says, `Provision Factory Defaults`, enable this and try.