# How to create platform key for secure boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am using dual boot with Ubuntu & Windows 10.

Since I try to upgrade to Kernel 5.x, I get boot problems ([cannot boot 5.x: Couldn't get UEFI db list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158780/cannot-boot-5-x-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list/1158883))

The answer seems to be to enable secure boot. However, I can't enable it in bios - I get the message that I have to create a platform key (PK) first. How does one create that?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Probably you have some setting for Secure Boot that says custom. Try changing it to standard. Then, optionally, disable Secure Boot again.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have made a screenshot of my Bios setting. For `Secure Boot Mode` are two options, `Standard` and `Custom`. It was set on `Standard`. There is another option called `Secure Boot Support`  which is disabled. When I try to enable it, I get the message from above.