# MODSIGN: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e Couldn't get UEFI db list

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, lenovo

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on a Lenovo 720 13" and I get the error in the title.

[image: MODSIGN: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e]

I looked for similar cases [1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380700) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095766/ubuntu-bootable-drive-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e-modsign-couldnt) [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158780/cannot-boot-5-x-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list) [4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169267/8-796763-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e) [5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179177/installing-ubuntu-cannot-disable-fast-boot-and-no-partitions-showing) [6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152072/gparted-not-showing-m-2-nvme-ssd) [7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot). I'm sure there are many more, so if I missed a solution, please point it out, but unfortunately the proposed solutions didn't seem to be effective in my case.

I tried:

- Secure Boot both enabled and disabled
- Fast Boot both enabled and disabled
- with and without creating empty space on the SSD
- Creating an ext4 partition from Windows
- Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04

The result is always the same. The installation doesn't recognize any partition, but mysterious 8.2GB (my RAM?) which are < to the 8.6 required.

The live version of Ubuntu runs, but even GParted doesn't recognize any disk apart the USB drive.

I apologize if I have missed a solution but there are many similar cases. Maybe the pictures in [this album](https://photos.app.goo.gl/cqHjLgbpgGHnFDGz8) can represent the situation
better than my words. I suspect the issue might be related to Lenovo,
so I'm also bothering them [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-720-Linux-installation-issue/m-p/4648811).

Comment: Lenovo: UEFI update required for USB-C port issues 2017 thru 2019 models And you typically need both UEFI update & SSD firmware update Secure boot off, UEFI fast boot off. Windows fast start up off. And in UEFI have drive set for AHCI, not Intel RST or Optane. Lenovo Yoga S740     [SOLVED] Installation problem
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2433373
Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL i5-8265U
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182889/install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-730-15iwl-with-a-i5-8265u-cpu-alongside-windows

Comment: oldfred as for the main post I have tried w/ secure boot OFF, fast boot OFF and win fast startup OFF already; the only thing I have left to try is to set the drive for AHCI, 
do you think that this is the solution?

Comment: Not having drives in AHCI mode has been a blocker, Linux does not support Intel RST. If  dual booting with Windows you have to first install Windows AHCI drivers. You said you experimented with the other settings. The suggestion was for the combination that should work.

Comment: it did works! you are the first one to "add ahci variables", thank you @oldfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for the solution to oldfred
the missing piece was switching from RAID to AHCI
which I did following [this](https://superuser.com/a/1359471).
(Writing this answer from Bionic Beaver)
Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on an empty disk. At first I thought the software didn't recognize my M.2 SSD, but it was completely different. I managed to get the live system running. Then I created an ESP partition, an ext4 partition and separate `/home` partition with GParted. With another live CD, [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/), I installed grub. After that I retried again with Ubuntu 18.04 bootable media. I got some kind of command line interface, added  the `nomodeset` kernel boot option at the end of "Linux", pressed F10 to continue, and off it went. It seems to be a known bug in Ubiquity. Nevertheless, 20 minutes later I was up and running.

Comment: uh... I forgot to mention the ext4 partition (from windows) in the question, I tried that too. How did you installed grub? (or better, where?)

Comment: I downloaded this ISO : https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

Comment: M.2 is a specification for internally mounted computer expansion cards and associated connectors. As such it doesn't provide any information about what device is mounted in the M.2 socket, whether it is a SATA or PCI-e device, an NVMe SSD or a non-NVMe SSD.

Comment: @Karel, normally it should not be a problem. Fire up a live-disk and start setup. On my MSI X470, I had troubles starting the live-session. Hence I tried the live-CD from Gparted to build partitions. Mind you, this not Gpart from the *buntu disks, but a fully fledged Partitioning Disk. and the lot didn't recognize the M.2 before it had the ESP up and formatted. After that , no problems anymore. Cheers

Comment: Hi again @Dirk, I've looked into your solution only today (I was in a trip) I might have express myself badly, I don't need restore a grub from a previous ubuntu installation, I cannot install ubuntu in the first place, on a second reading of your initial answer you mention creating a partition from live cd, I'm not in this condition; I can create / resize partition only from Windows, Grub still doesn't see anything.

Comment: Are you telling you cannot fire up your PC and boot into a live disk ? What options have you in your BIOS ?

Comment: I can run the live version, but when I select install grub doesn't see the free space in the disk or the ext4 partition, the bios settings I've tried are on the main thread; you can also see it for yourself here => https://photos.app.goo.gl/cqHjLgbpgGHnFDGz8

Comment: could this be solved switching to AHCI?
did any of you experienced that?
I'm worried to wipe everything out for nothing
or worse not be able to use it at all