# Kicked to initramfs after rebooting for no reason

Tags: boot, 16.04, acpi, initramfs, fsck

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an HP T620 Thin Client. Since a few days ago I've been struggling with this new issue. I started up  my PC normally, everything looked just fine, but Psensor indicator displayed only CPU usage (that caught my attention because I had configured GPU indication as well). I thought "OK fine, a restart could help", but after rebooting I was kicked to initramfs (for me, with no logical reason) with this information.

[image: this information]

Ubuntu suggested to perform fsck, so I did it. After that Ubuntu restarted properly, but concerned about my PC security (something corrupted important system files causing this whole "initramfs situation") I've run `dmesg` to view logs, and look for suspicious entries.

I found only this:

```
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI MokListRT

ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \HWMC, AE_AML_UNINITIALIZED_ELEMENT (20170831/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_UNINITIALIZED_ELEMENT (20170831/psparse-550)
```

Disk S.M.A.R.T parameters are good (checked it, even ran some diagnostics to be sure), I've changed nothing in BIOS (especially in power management settings).

What happened exactly? Should I be concerned about system security because it was caused by virus or something? I was looking for a similar thread in the forum, but I didn't find someone who had a similar problem.

**Edit:**
Ok, so today i decided to take a closer look on SMART logs, because problem is still present and i want to discover what is going on with my system and what caused data corruption which I meant earlier. I did short and long DST test from UEFI. Short passed, extended - failed. But this has no confirmation with tests done from OS (all tests passed) - until today. Today disk is reporting that did not passed any test, and has some uncorrectable errors. System itself does not hang, and does not show any symptoms that something is wrong.

Problem that i'm facing with is actually some bad sectors, bad blocks...? Is this disk failure has corelation with problem described earlier?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4TO2.png) [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LFI7.png)

Effect of `hdparm` command:

```
ubuntu@hp-t620:~$ sudo hdparm --read-sector 12032336 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
reading sector 12032336: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 03 00 00 00 00 0a 40 51 e0 01 11 04 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
succeeded
```

***Explanation of referral to another similar thread:**
Before I asked the question here, I tried to modify the grub attributes (as indicated in the question pointed by @user535733), but this did not bring the desired results.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e)

Comment: No. Errors still present in logs. I've tried this earlier with no effect.