# How to solve you are in emergency mode issue with sda2?

Tags: boot, 18.04, virtualbox, bootloader, kali

I am new to Ubuntu. 18.04. I installed Kali Linux in virtual box. And when I rebooted my Ubuntu it shows like this:

[image]

Then when I select Ubuntu:

[image]

[image]

Then again loading screen will show up and then this comes up:

[image]

What should I do about this?

Comment: You are presented a simple choice, clearly explained on the screen: To use CTRL+D to attempt a continued boot, or to review your logs to determine why emergency mode was triggered.

Comment: i pressed control + d but still the same

Comment: Hi. try booting from and USB Live ubuntu and do a filesystem check of your drives. they need to be unmounted.

Comment: how to do that. i am new

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e)