# How to fix dual booted Ubuntu unexpected crashes with error MODSIGN: couldn't get UEFI db list?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, lenovo, crash

I have Ubuntu 18.04 dual-booting on a Lenovo IdeaPad 320 notebook with Windows 10. It has an Intel i3 6th generation processor, 4GB RAM, and 2TB of HDD. Ubuntu has recently started showing errors. I try to restart my laptop but, after selecting Ubuntu from the boot menu, I receive the following error:

[image: MODSIGN: couldn't get UEFI db list]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: No, but I try this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e) which is similar to the above question but does not work. but after 1 hour when I try to boot ubuntu it boots successfully. I am facing the same problem many times and it solves automatically. I don't know what to do. now I don't want to see such an error again what should I try. I am now trying to update 18.04 to the latest version of ubuntu, can it help me..?

Comment: Hello. There is no such version of Ubuntu as 18. A good place to start with any question is an accurate version number.

Comment: I know 18 is not vali version but try to understand i don't remember exact version and my system not booting. As i said before after solved issues automatically i try to upgrade ubantu to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS but not it not working after upgrade. I still can not able to boot my ubuntu.

Comment: If you keep having these errors sometimes, it might be better to make a list of your installed software, make a backup, and do a clean install of 20.04.4. (which you can upgrade to 22.04 end of April). I do not say that upgrading your system now will solve the problem, nor am I saying that it won't.

Comment: Did Windows do an UEFI update which may have reset some UEFI settings you originally changed when you installed Ubuntu. It may have turned UEFI Secure Boot back on as modsign is related to secure boot type issue. UEFI updates reset to defaults. I have to keep a list on one system as it as multiple settings I change, some required, some optional to make system boot faster. But I do not have Windows, so know when I do an UEFI update.

Comment: Windows updates will sometimes screw up the UEFI-settings. You can use a little program called ```super_grub2_disk_hybrid```. It is available as an``` iso``` and is around 20 MB. If you make a USB stick with ```Ventoy```, you can put ```Ubuntu 20.04.4.iso``` and ```super_grub2_disk_hybrid.iso``` on it. This program will recognize all your bootable operating systems and can boot them. So you can easyly boot into your Ubuntu, do a ```sudo update-grub``` and your done.

Comment: My laptop is now now more than 5 years old . Some time while i using windows it shows no bootable drieve found .I think it cause due to dust in my laptop what do you think.How can i check my overall hardware health of my laptop. 2 days ago i freshly  installed ubantu 20.04 LTS and now it works good. but sometimes it lag. It is due to dust..?